# Spring rest service array as property of object

Tags: json, spring, rest, spring-mvc, jackson

So, here is my problem,

I have class :

```
Class1 {
String prop1;
int prop2;

public Class1() {
}

setters/getters
}
```

And antoher one:

```
Class2{
String prop1;
List<Class1> porp2;

public Class2(){
}
getters/setters
}
```

And in controller which handle request:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/path", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
String saveJingle(@RequestBody Class2 class2) throws NamingException {
}
```

And if I send following json:

```
{
prop1: 'ada',
prop2: [{'prop1':'asdad', 'prop2':'gkfjg'}]
}
```

And I'm getting 400 Error.
How to fix this.

Thanks

Comment: Is `Class1#prop2` really an `int`? If you turn your log levels to DEBUG, Spring will tell you the problem.

Comment: No it's not int in real example, but I think that isn't problem in this case.

Answer (score 0):

My fault, this works by default as expected, I have made syntax mistake.